# cross browser issues jquery dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu, onclick

Ok I made a site a while back and always had issues with the menu system is needed. Basically you click a location on a map, then it displays the list of sub locations in the dropdown menu to the right. These are always their they just chance to display based on the options class.

I have put the site at shiftera.co.uk so you can see it their.

The issue first.
1) IE - The list never filters out, it displays all results all the time regardless of class.
2) Chrome - The dropdown is sometimes squashed showing 1 result and hiding the others you need to use up/down arrows to change, sometimes it shows 3, sometimes 4. 
3) Firefox - The list displays in 1 long row, not like a usual dropdown.

I think the issue is more of a css problem or multitude of css problems.

An example of the map link is

```
<a href="Scotland#browse" class="areaselect" id="Scotland" title="Scotland">Scotland</a>
```

The dropdown list although not seperated is generated from the database and appears as below

```
<option value='AB25 1UH' class="Scotland">Aberdeen</option><option value=' WA14 4DW' class="Northwest">Altrincham</option>
```

As you can see, some have the space before some don't. The dropdown has the id of apick and Im using css below to hide it on load.

```
#apick { display: none; }
```

Here is the javascript to display the correct items based on map click.

```
//<![CDATA[ 
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.areaselect').on('click', function(event){
        $('#apick').css('display','inline');
        var id = $(this).attr('id')
        $('#apick option').not('.'+id).css('display','none');
        $('.'+id).css('display','inline').first().attr('selected','selected');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
}); //]]>
```

This has been driving me mad for a long time now, it seem's if i fix 1 issue another 2-3 get created. So I figured i'd try here and see if any brightspark can narrow down my issue.

- Updated removing windows load as per change to main website.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that you are setting the style to inline. An `<option>` tag should not be inline, or have any style like that. The inline style i causing the problems.

Instead add the `<option>` tags when you need them. Store all the values in a object to add/remove them.

By the way. Remove that window load thing.

Here is the javascript fix:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var options = $('#apick option');
    var values = $.map(options, function(option)
    {
        return option;
    });

    $('.areaselect')
        .on('click', function()
        {
            var apick = $('#apick').empty();
            var id = $(this).attr('id');

            var newValues = $.grep(values, function(n, i)
            {
                return $(n).hasClass(id);
            });

            apick.append(newValues).show().find('option:first').attr('selected','selected');

            return false;
        });
});
```

Comment: I was originally running the query via a jquery loader each time they clicked on the map but the same issues where occurring. Or are you referring to a different method, if possible can you show me an example?

Comment: I can see at your website the code works. Please accept the answer to close this question.